# Programmatically retrieve content from WYSIHTML5 editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor, wysiwyg, wysihtml5

How do I programmatically retrieve content from a `WYSIHTML5` editor?
Suppose the editor is instantiated as this:

```
var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor
(
   $(this.el).find('textarea').get(0),
   {
      toolbar:      "toolbar",
      parserRules:  wysihtml5ParserRules
   }
);
```

i would like to get the editor's content on `blur` event

```
editor.on
(
   "blur",
   function()
   {
      //what here?
   }
);
```

Comment: You can either look at the docs of that editor or retrieive it from *rendered* output of it by inspecting through console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's much better to use the API
`editor.getValue()`

(@dalen mentioned this in the comment above)

Answer (score 5):

Here is how (using jQuery here):

```
$('iframe').contents().find('.wysihtml5-editor').html();
```

To find text instead, use `text()` instead of `html()`.

FYI:

- I jQuerified [this demo page](http://xing.github.com/wysihtml5/examples/advanced.html) of it using [jQueryify bookmarklet](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/jquerify-bookmarklet)
- Entered some text in editor
- typed above code at console and output was entered text

*In your application, you won't need the jQueryify bookmarklet, I used it to inject jQuery on that demo page so that I could use it to get the value of editor.*

---

Having said that, there normally should be some built-in method in that editor to get current value you should look at the docs :)

Comment: I've actually looked for that method on the docs but couldn't find it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Dalen: You are welcome. Try at console `console.log(editor)` just after you create the instance of editor (`new wysihtml5.Editor`) . It would list all members of it.

Comment: As you suggested printing editor into console, turns out that it has a method called `getValue` that does what I was looking for. Thanks again